# Embed image to vsix

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, embedded-resource, vsix

I'm playing around with the custom start page template in vs.

How would I go about embedding an image that I can use the in the start page xaml.  I have tried the normal way of setting the image to Resource and setting the source property on the Image control to the file name.

```
<Image Source="logo.jpg" />
```

but it doesn't work...it builds ok and spins up the start page ok, but doesn't show the image.  If I stick in a url to the source that works fine.

Thx
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you have to set the Source like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/logo.jpg" />
```

Comment: thanks.  thought that was it then...that displays in the designer, same as mine. but when i spin it up I get an error.  "Cannot display absolute URI"

Comment: oh wait, I just bult a little dummy project and got it to work like you had in your question: I added a jpg, set it as resource, and it worked... is your image on the root of your project folder? if not, write its relative path into the source: `<Image Source="Images/1.jpg"></Image>` ..

Comment: yeah its in the root of the project.  images shows fine in the designer, but when I debug.  no image!

Comment: just got it to work by putting the image in another project <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Assembly;component/images/logo.jpg"

Comment: I'm trying to add image into my dummy WPF control in property window of VSIX package - same story: image is visible in designer, but does not show up in VS2012 being debugged. I've tried these recommendations above - does not work for me :( - what is this "pack:' protocol? I have "Resources\start.png" in my project marked as "Build Action=Resource" and refer it in XAML as <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Assembly;component/Resources/start.png" />

Comment: Absoutelly weird thing - after doing some code changes simple <Image Source="Resources/start.png" /> does work too. I expect VSIX package was just not built 'correctly' for some reason. Anywhy - i have no idea why it was not working and why it does work now. Probably clean rebuild will help next time.

Comment: @FilipeMiguel: I tried your suggestion, but it's not working for me. Any suggestion at all ?
I believe we don't have an answer for this specific question  yet...

Answer (score 5):

If the **Build Action** is **Resource** in the Properties window:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/logo.jpg" />
```

If the **Build Action** is **Content** and **Include in VSIX** is **True** in the Properties window:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,/Resources/logo.jpg" />
```

Considering the **logo.jpg** is in the **Resources** folder.

Comment: The first one(Build Action=>resource), works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Source like this

```
   <Image Source="pack://application:,/Resources/view.png" Margin="5"/>
```

Then you had to mark the picture in the Properties Section as **Content** and set the **Include in VSIX** to **True**.

Hope that would help, 
Greetings from Noxum